# How to read UTF-8 string from Socket in ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, sockets, utf-8

UTF-8 has varying amount of bytes per character. How can I understand how much bytes I can read by `flash.net.Socket.readUTFBytes(length:uint):String`?

Comment: have you tried anything? how about bytesAvailable?

Comment: Is it guaranteed that loaded bytes constitute UTF-8 string? Maybe some bytes of the last character weren't loaded yet.

Answer (score 0):

There is a property available in your `Socket` object that will contain the information needed:

```
mySocket.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA, _onSocketDataHandler);

private function _onSocketDataHandler(e:ProgressEvent):void
{
    var str:String = mySocket.readUTFBytes(mySocket.bytesAvailable);

    trace(str);
}
```

Comment: Yes, It could be a solution. Will it await the yet unloaded part of the string?

Comment: Actually, ignore my previous answer. I've updated the answer with a better solution.